# Multiple histogram from a raster image in R

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, zonal-statistics, histogram

I need to get multiple histograms from a  tif image. I have the following data:

A big raster tif image:

```
tif1 <- raster("myRaster.tif")
hist(tif1, breaks= 10) # gives the entire histogram
```

A shapefile of a country. This shapefile contains a polygon for each administrative area:

```
shp_np <- readOGR("NPL_adm2.shp")
```

I can think of a way to get the histogram by repetitively cropping raster tif using each Polygon in shapefile one by one. But, it is not efficient.

Now, I am searching for easy way to get the histogram information for each polygon in the shapefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `extract` function from the `raster` package to get the values for each polygon. That should be quicker than trying to use `crop` or `mask` for every polygon.

Alternatively,`rasterize` the polygons on the same basis as your raster. That gets you a raster with values from 1 to the number of polygons. You can then treat your rasters as R vectors and use `tapply` to apply a function to subsets of the raster.